# SSL Certificate chain mocking

Tags: python, requests-mock

I would like to test couple of methods that involves Python *requests* library. Cases I'd like to cover are:

1. server unreachable
2. server reachable, but targeted service not
   available
3. call failed
4. call succeeded

Now the tricky part is, I need to cover also SSL certificates failure(s):

1. valid
2. expired
3. missing/invalid one certificate in chain

Is this possible with requests-mock or other library?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: It seems like the easiest thing to do here is to generate certificates as part of your test setup and configure an http server to use them. You can create a trivial https server [using the `http` module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19706670/147356).

Comment: @larsks Thanks, I was also thinking about it, but not sure is this the right approach. If I don't find anything more suitable, will go that path for sure.